# exclude specific folder from library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a library that is incompatible with java8. It's xws-security:3.0. I can't use it fully because there's trouble in `crypto/xmldsig/1.0`.

On the screenshot, you can see situation in the intellij idea.

How can I solve this problem by gradle exclude?

[image: situation in the intellij idea]

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from repository and then install it into your local repo. https://springframework.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/springframework/repos/repo-ext/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/xmldsig-1.0.jar

Code:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=xmldsig-1.0.jar -DgroupId=javax.xml.crypto -DartifactId=xmldsig -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DcreateChecksum=true
```